# Bundling to UMD removed from Angular 15

Tags: angular, bundle, angular15, umd

From angular 13 and higher version **Bundling to UMD** step was removed from the dist folder, does anyone knows how does it works now for a library project it looks like there is not way around to have those UMD. How can I make sure that this is working, I was reading and all relates to Ivy from Angular

Comment: Looks like the UMD is deprecated since then is not longer needed I found a couple of option create a webpack config, rollup lib. But end up with a quick solution by adding a extra property in the angular.json options called preserveSymlinks loos like is needed in major versions and most when it is prod enviroments